# How to add buttons or icons properly next to a text?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I want to place a button right next to a text like ion-label. But when I do so, the button is right next to the text while somehow shifted and not properly aligned to the text in a line. What can I change so it looks prettier?

page.html

```
<h6>text•&nbsp;text•&nbsp;<ion-button shape="round"></ion-button></h6>
```

page.scss

```
 h6{
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-size: 12.5px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we see your CSS for this element as well please?

Comment: I added it. But I get this strange behavior in the whole project. Everywhere I want to place a button or an icon next to a text.

Comment: Do you have a CSS library which styles the `ion-button`?

Comment: Has the button a margin-left?

Comment: the `<ion-button>` is default. No css

Comment: It must have some *default* styling! - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, vertically-aligning buttons (and other inline-block elements) with text can be done by setting `vertical-align:middle` on the button. I do this for badges that I display next to text inside of free-flowing text elements.

```css
ion-button {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h6>
  text•&nbsp;text•&nbsp;
  <ion-button shape="round"></ion-button>
</h6>
```

In your specific case, though, I can't tell how your `h6` is really being used. (Probably not semantically.) Sometimes, getting buttons or badges to vertically-align is better done by using the slots of one of the Ionic wrapping elements, like an `ion-toolbar` or an `ion-item`.

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>text• text•</ion-label>
  <ion-button shape="round" slot="end"></ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ion-badge for this(https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/badge)

```
<ion-button>Button name<ion-badge color="primary" slot="end">11</ion-badge></in-button>
```